# Forbids comparing pointer with integer?

Tags: c++, dice

I'm coding a game of farkle, and I run into this problem even though all but two of my if statements are bools.

Also, how would I go about letting a user roll specific dice? BloodshedDev/othre IDEs seem to not be working in windows 8 yet, so I'm using Ideone and having zero luck with any of this.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
using namespace std;

//global vars
int bubblehold;
int roll[6];
int score;
int bank;
int dicecatch;
int tempscore = 0;
int dicenum = 6;

//function prototype
void bubblesort(int[], int);
bool straightsix();
bool sixkind();
bool fivekind();
bool fourkind();
bool threekind();
int onefive();

int main() {
    srand(time(0));
        for(int i=0; i=dicenum-1; i++){
        roll[i] = rand()%6+1;
    }
    bubblesort(roll,dicenum);
    for(int i=0; i=dicenum-1; i++){
        cout<< roll[i] <<", ";
    }

    if(straightsix == true){
        tempscore = 1500;

    }
    else if(sixkind == true){
        tempscore = 3000;

    }
    else if(fivekind == true){
        tempscore = 2000;

    }
    else if(fourkind == true){
        tempscore = 1000;
    }
    else if(threekind == true){
        cout<< tempscore;
    }
    else if(onefive == 1){
        tempscore = dicecatch * tempscore;
        cout<< tempscore;
    }
    else if(onefive == 5){
        tempscore = dicecatch * tempscore;
        cout<< tempscore;
    }

    return 0;
}
void bubblesort(int a[], int x){
    for (int i = 0; i < x-1; i++){
        bubblehold = a[i+1];
        a[i+1] = a[i];
        a[i] = bubblehold;
    }
}
bool straightsix(){
    for(int i=0; i<5; i++){
        if(roll[i]+1 != roll[i+5]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
bool sixkind(){
    for(int i=0; i=5; i++){
        if (roll[i] != roll[i+5]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
bool fivekind(){
    for(int i=0; i=4; i++){
        if (roll[i] != roll[i+4]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
bool fourkind(){
    for(int i=0; i=3; i++){
        if (roll[i] != roll[i+3]){
            return false;
        }
    }
}
bool threekind(){
    for(int i=0; i=2; i++){
        if (roll[i] != roll[i+2]){
            return false;
        }
        else if(i=1){
            dicecatch = 3;
            tempscore = dicecatch * 100;
            return true;
        }
        else{
            dicecatch = i;
            tempscore = dicecatch * 100;
            return true;
        };
    }
}

int onefive(){
    for(int i=0; i=dicenum; i++){
        if(roll[i] == 1){
            dicecatch = dicecatch + 1;
            tempscore = tempscore + 100;
            return 1;
        }
        else if(roll[i] == 5){
            dicecatch = dicecatch + 1;
            tempscore = tempscore + 50;
            return 5;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: I think you meant `if(straightsix() == true)` etc, etc, etc.

Comment: *"I run into this problem"*  What problem?  Where?

Comment: You shouldn't write this much code without testing any of it.

Comment: @user657267: Or, *much* better, `if (straightsix())`. It's already a boolean value; why add a useless comparison?

Comment: Your `bubblesort` doesn't produce a sorted result.

Comment: Global variables are bad. I have no idea what your various kind functions are doing.

Comment: You know, if you just defined the functions before their first use, you could get rid of all those declarations...

Comment: You've probably noticed that a lot of your code is getting negative attention.  Since you are new to C++, I think @Beta gave the best advice here.  Write a much smaller program and then see if it works.  Then add a little code and see if it works.

Answer (score 0):

In this line,

```
if(straightsix == true){
```

you are comparing a function pointer with `true`. You have similar statements involving other functions.

Perhaps you meant to use:

```
if(straightsix() == true){
```

In that case, it can be simplified to:

```
if(straightsix()){
```

Comment: Drop the `== true`. It's useless.

Answer (score 0):

Expanding a bit the [answer of R Sahu](https://stackoverflow.com/a/28143528/2557263), the difference is effectively just the added parenthesis, but I would like to add the reason.

In C++ (and actually all other C-style languages I know of) when you're referring to functions having parenthesis is a big difference. Putting them on means that the code will **call** the function, execute all its code, and whatever it returns will be used in the comparison afterwards. The parenthesis also are a fundamental syntax for passing parameters, and are mandatory even if you don't pass any when calling, unlike basic-style languages and many others.

Omitting parenthesis has a radically different meaning. Instead of instructing execution of a function, it will return a [pointer](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pointer_(computer_programming)) to the function and will never run any of its code. That pointer is obviously not a boolean and neither an *int*, that gives the compiler error most likely. All your *if* in the *main* have this problem.

A correct usage of function calls are the initial call to *time* and *srand*, including the parenthesis and argument (a zero) within them.